# Import Certificate into SQL Server 2008R2 running on Windows7

Tags: sql-server, iis, ssl-certificate

I have a SQL Server 2008R2 running on a Windows 7 Home Premium, I access the database from a remote PC over the internet. This works but the data are transmitted in plain text.

Now I want to enable SSL.

I tried several tutorials.

What I can do in the moment is the following:

1. Create a self-signed certificate in IIS 7
   (Steps one to four of the following tutorial)
   http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-in-iis-7.html
2. Assign the certificate to the SQL Server instance

   A. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager

   B. Right click on 'Protocol on ' (for the instance which we need, here it is `STANDARD`)

   C. In the certificate tab and select the certificate we created earlier.

   D. Click on Apply and restart the SQL Server instance to get this change applied.
3. This works for localhost: if I connect with SQL Server Management Studio running on the same machine as SQL Server it works with the option "Encrypted Connection" activated.

Before I imported the self created certificate It did not work to connect with the option "Encrypted Connection" activated.[image]

4. If I want to connect with SQL Server Management Studio with the option "Encrypted Connection" activated from a remote PC outside the local network I get this error:

[image]

> Cannot Connect to home2server.de,50021\SQLServer Additional Information: A Connection was established, but the Certificate was signed from a not trustworthy certification center.

I exported the certificate to `SQL_cert.pfx` with IIS and copied this file on the remote PC who wants to access the database. Then I double clicked on it and imported it.

Now I get a new error:

> The CN Name of the Certificate does not match with the given value.

My guess is that the certificate is issued for `database-pc` (the computer name of the PC where SQL Server is running). This is the reason it works for "localhost" as the server name.

I think I have to issue a certificate which is issued for `home2server.de` because this is the domain that redirects the connection to `database-pc`.

Is my thought true ? And if yes how can I issue a certificate like this?

Answer (score 0):

Add an entry to your `hosts` file that maps `home2server.de` to `127.0.0.1` (or `::1`), then use `home2server.de` when connecting locally.

...or don't encrypt local communications.